# Add geom_abline to time series plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have some values through time, I want to plot them and manually add a trend line using `geom_abline()`. When I add the line nothing shows up. E.g.

```
library(ggplot2)

# example data
df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18603, 16965, 17294, 16111, 18274, 18820,
                                   17658, 17056, 17448, 18757, 16902, 16594,
                                   16447, 16027, 18330, 16685, 17210, 18694,
                                   15778, 16755), class = "Date"), 
               Value = c(5.37, 1.95, 3.72, 7.55, 5.05, 3.1, 1.43, 3.45, 
                         7.1, 1.44, 4, 4.3, 6.9, 8.01, 1.61, 3.3, 1.4, 8.46,
                         8.78, 8.3)), class = "data.frame",
          row.names = c(NA, -20L))



# plot just the line - works fine
intc <- 3.57
slope <- 0.1

ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = intc, slope = slope)
```

[image]

```
# adding the point data makes the line disappear
 ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = intc, slope = slope) +
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(x = Date, y = Value))
```

[image]

Any adice on how I can get the trend line and the points on the same plot would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might use `geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)` to do this more simply.

Comment: Unfortunately I have fit a model separately (not an lm) so that option doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @542goweast mentions, it's a bit convoluted since your x-axis has the class of Date. And dates are represented as integers where `0 == as.numeric(as.Date("1970-01-01"))`. So the axis does not start at 0 and instead starts at `as.numeric(min(df1$Date)) -> 15778`.

Additionally since the x-axis units are by day you need to scale your slope and intercept accordingly.

Below is an option.

```
num_of_days = as.numeric(difftime(max(df1$Date), min(df1$Date)), unit = "days")
slope = .1 / num_of_days
intc = 3.57 - slope*min(as.numeric(df1$Date))

ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = Date, y = Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10)) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = intc, slope = slope))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your `slope` object. Once you add the data points, your x-axis is on the scale of 2000's. At that scale, such a line would appear approximately vertical. On the first hash mark - 2014 - we would have a y value of about 205. Try `slope=0.0001`.

Comment: hmm I see. using `slope=0.0001` does indeed show up, but now the intercept is way off.

Comment: You could try normalizing your x-axis scale to 2/4/6/8, and then either doing what @JonSpring suggested or by running a linear regression using `lm` and then looking at the coefficients